# Windows Vista: TCP/IP stack is smashed, how to reinstall the LAN-Devices?

Tags: networking, windows-vista, tcpip

the TCP/IP stack is smashed, thats why no LAN-Connections are running. I want to download the LAN drivers from another computer and uninstall and reinstall the LAN devices on this system. Hopefully that should recreate the stack.

- But what to download?
- What uninstall?
- How to install?

Windows Vista is protected against such changes, so how to achieve that job? please help.

**Update per 2011-03-11:**

I found all the tipps and hints about "TCP/IP Repair, LSP Fix, and WinSock Fix" according to windows vista **but nothing helped** to bring back network access.

What can i do as next step or which opportunities are left?

Comment: It may not be compatible with Vista (though it seems to work), but in XP, there were several tools that could do this when all else (eg `netsh … reset`) failed: TCP/IP Repair, LSP Fix, and WinSock Fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following command using an elevated command prompt:

> netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

To get an elevated command prompt, press your windows key, type "cmd", and then right click on the "cmd.exe" icon that appears in the search results and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I allready have done this, with no success.

Comment: @Ice - Then Don't accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login as a user with Administrator access if you can't disable UAC (User Account Control).  Unfortunately UAC is a feature that, although well-intended, tends to cause more confusion and interference than it is helpful (and so most users just disable it so they don't have to keep answering "Yes" -- SpyWare and Viruses seem to get installed regardless of how strict UAC is set anyway).

What type of NIC do you have in your system now?  That is a very important piece of information for determining where to get the drivers next.

Also:  Rebooting into Safe Mode will typically provide an additional "Administrator" account login option that doesn't normally appear in Windows Vista Home Edition.

Comment: Try Joel's suggestion first -- it's a lot easier and may resolve your problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with UAC -- the trick is to disable it during the first 6 weeks or so with a new computer, while you're still installing apps and getting most of your settings configured.  After that "break-in period" the prompts settle down a lot.  I think if Microsoft had designed the feature to pop up one month after activation and ask if you want to turn it on, people would be singing it's praises.

Comment: If there really was nothing wrong with UAC, then why did Microsoft change it so significantly in Windows 7?  This interesting document examines UAC's good and bad points:  http://www.replaceuac.com/articles/great-protection-or-great-irritation.html

Comment: UAC is no Problem for me! 
Safe Mode, will this prevent vista in imediately reinstalling removed devices? i could not replace a file after remove of the device.

Comment: Yes, Safe Mode is there to make dealing with misbehaving drivers easier.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled windows vista. It was the only thing that re-enabled network functionality.